# Managing IOS Developer AND IOS Enterprise Developer accounts

Tags: ios

There has been a lot of questions on this already that answer some of my questions. I am looking for someone who has direct experience with setting up and managing both accounts.

I have a situation where I need to send a private Beta test to more than 100 people (the ad-hoc device limit for iOS), but I still want to be able to publish publicly to the app store.

My solution is to obtain both an enterprise account and a regular developer account. The enterprise account allows me to distribute to anyone within my company, privately with no limit. The regular account gives me the ability to publish to the app store. Unfortunately this means I have two create two different apple developer accounts.

I am worried about the hidden caveats that are involved with this process.

- Is there any caveats with managing two separate apple developer accounts for the same application?
- Any problem with packaging names for applications? I'm assuming the identifier needs to be different.
- I hear that you cannot test the storekit with the enterprise program. Any other problems similiar to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experience with managing both Developer and Enterprise a/c. We have multiple applications in appstore. We mainly use the enterprise a/c for testing and developer's a/c for publishing the application to app store. This has worked fine for us for more than a year now.

That being said, managing two accounts is cumbersome. I have no idea why Apple won't allow us to create App Store distribution profile using the Enterprise a/c! Here are few recommendations:

- Choose the names of the accounts so that you could easily distinguish them e.g. "xxx developer" and "xxx enterprise".
- It is possible to create the developer and ad-hoc distribution profiles in both the accounts. Overtime it can become messy especially if you have multiple developers and applications. So I would recommend forming some guidelines for the accounts usage beforehand.
- You can use the [Wildcard App Id](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1713/_index.html) when creating the distribution profile. So you can avoid changing the Apple Id for the same application in these accounts. However, if you use Push Notifications and/or In App Purchase then you will have to use explicit App Id, and App Id needs to be different in each account.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. I will accept after waiting for more responses.

Comment: One question. Is there any restrictions on devices for the unlimited in-house distributions? i.e. Can all the employees of the company load the apps on their personal cellphones?

Comment: I am not aware of any restrictions on devices for in-house distribution as long as it on the device used by a person associated with the company.

Comment: How do you handle App IDs between accounts?  I'm assuming both accounts cannot share the same ID.